# Закрыть приложение при питании ноутбука от аккумулятора

Tags: cmd, windows-10, bat, wmi

Например, нужно закрыть приложение торрента.
Такой вариант не работает

```
if (wmic path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus) == 1 (
  cd C:\Users\npetr\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent
  taskkill /IM uTorrent.exe /F
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Он и не должен работать, так как не является корректным с точки зрения синтаксиса: результатом запроса `wmic` будет не число, а строковые литералы, а суть перехода `cd` вообще неясна. Иными словами, верной будет запись:

```
@echo off
  setlocal
    set "wql=wmic path win32_battery get batterystatus"
    for /f %%i in ('%wql% ^| findstr /irc:"[0-9]"') do (
      if %%i equ 1 wmic process where name="utorrent.exe" call terminate
    )
  endlocal
exit /b
```